# Octave cannot plot spectrogram

Tags: plot, octave

I am using the code in octave to print a Spectogram like these . The code is from a lab manual but i am getting errors.
[image]

The code

```
[x, Fs, bps] = wavread('digit.wav');

alpha=0.5; %Overlap
N=256;% 32ms window size
figure(2)
clf()
specgram(x,N,Fs,hanning(N),alpha*N);
xlabel('Time (s)', "fontsize", 18)
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)', "fontsize", 18)
```

The error

```
>> spectogram
warning: wavread is obsolete and will be removed from a future version of Octave,please use audioread instead
warning: called from
    wavread at line 62 column 5
    spectogram at line 1 column 11
error: 'specgram' undefined near line 7 column 1
error: called from
    spectogram at line 7 column 1
```

Comment: Any code even in python will help me

Answer (score 2):

1. As the warning suggests, `wavread` is obsolete and you should use `audioread` instead
2. The `specgram` function is part of the `signal` package. To use it you should load the signal package first: `pkg load signal`. If you don't have it installed already, install it from octave forge first: `pkg install signal -forge`.

Comment: Its giving the error and these is no      `  >> spectogram.m
parse error near line 12 of file /home/rutherford/spectogram.m  syntax error` and there is nothing in line 12. I added pkg load signal at the beginning of the script to load the signal package. Where am I going wrong

Comment: I removed bps and it worked thanks Tasos Papastylianou